# Insert XML document into existing XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

Given these XML documents:

**Document 1**

```
<root>
  <element1>
  </element1>
</root>
```

**Document 2**

```
<request>
  <dummyValue>5</dummyValue>
</request>
```

Using Pythons `ElementTree` I'd like to insert the second document into the first document so that the result would look as follows.

**Resulting document**

```
<root>
  <element1>
    <request>
      <dummyValue>5</dummyValue>
    </request>
  </element1>
</root>
```

`ET.SubElement(element1, request)` gives me a serialization error.

Is there a Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: If you have code that produces an error, please reduce that code to the shortest possible **complete** example that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SubElement()`](http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-elementtree-ElementTree.htm#elementtree.ElementTree.SubElement-function) constructs an `Element` and then attaches it to the tree. Since you already have `request` as an `Element`, you don't need to construct a new one.

Try `element1.append(request)`, like so:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc1 = ET.XML('''
<root>
  <element1>
  </element1>
</root>
''')

request = ET.XML('''
<request>
  <dummyValue>5</dummyValue>
</request>
''')

for element1 in doc1.findall('element1'):
    element1.append(request)

ET.dump(doc1)
```